# Can an “if-clause” be used as an extraposed subject?

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjects, extraposition

When a subject is a *whether*-clause, it can be extraposed:

> [**Whether (or not)** he comes] makes no difference.　　*(basic version)*
>   *It* makes no difference [**whether (or not)** he comes].　　*(extraposed)*

The logical subject is "extraposed", pulled out of its basic position and moved to the end of the sentence.  Since the sentence needs a grammatical subject, dummy *it* appears in its place at the beginning.

---

Can an *if*-clause be used as an extraposed subject, too?

> *[**If** he comes] makes no difference.　　*(basic version)*
>   *It* makes no difference [**if** he comes].　　*(extraposed)*

Is the extraposed version okay?  It's unclear because the basic version seems to be ungrammatical.

Comment: It's "natural enough", but note that ***whether*** is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+makes+no+difference+if%2CIt+makes+no+difference+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20makes%20no%20difference%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIt%20makes%20no%20difference%20whether%3B%2Cc0) than ***if*** in such constructions.

Comment: Since this question asked about a "real subject", it was clear to me that it was about extraposition.  With that in mind, I elaborated on the question a little.  It should be clear now that this isn't a duplicate―the other question is not about extraposition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sentence sounds natural. It's a little more common to use "whether" in place of "if" in a sentence like this one--where two options are being presented ('he comes' or 'he doesn't come').

> It makes no difference whether he comes or not.